# What is the origin of the name "Artscroll"

Tags: names, etymology, artscroll

If I were naming a company dedicated to bringing Jewish soures to the masses, I would choose a name more descriptive of the mission than "Artscroll". What is the origin of this name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [an interview](http://www.vosizneias.com/44268/2009/12/06/new-york-interview-the-pepole-behind-the-artscroll-revolution/), the name comes because the publisher made fancy ketubot:

> Y.H. [interviewer]: If I remember correctly, ArtScroll started off publishing fancy high-end kesubos…
>
> N[osson] S[cherman of ArtScroll]: Yes, ArtScroll’s name came from that. Meir Zlotowitz had a
>   company that was involved in such printing.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArtScroll) says the following:

> In 1975,[1] Zlotowitz, a graduate of Mesivtha Tifereth Jerusalem, was
>   director of a high-end graphics studio in New York.[2] The firm, named
>   ArtScroll Studios,[1] produced brochures,[3] invitations, awards and
>   ketubahs.[1]… The name
>   ArtScroll was chosen for the publishing company to emphasize the
>   visual appeal of the books.[7]